# Como eliminar varios valores repetidos de un select html?

Tags: angular, firebase, typescript

quiero hacer un select donde muestre los nombres, pero que estos no se repitan. Estos datos se encuentran en firebase ya que tengo una funcion que se llama obtenerEsport y mi codigo es este en ngOnInit():

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.serveiAutenticar.obtenerEsport()
    .snapshotChanges()
    .subscribe(item =>{
      this.listaEsport = [];
      item.forEach(element => {
        let x = element.payload.toJSON();
        x["$key"] = element.key;
        this.listaEsport.push(x as Esports);
         
      });
    });
    this.resetForm();
  }
```

Y en el select hacia esto :

```
<select  class="form-control" name="esport" #esport="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="serveiAutenticar.selectedEsportista.esport">
   <option  *ngFor= "let esport of llistaEsport" value="{{esport.name}}">{{esport.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Pero claro aquí me muestra todos los nombres incluso los repetidos, he probado con ng-repeat pero ni idea de como usarlo ya que hace poco que me he metido en angular,typescript... Alguna ayuda se agradece.

Comment: Antes hacer `this.listaEsport.push(x as Esports);` añade una comprobación de si existe ya: `if(!this.listaEsport.contains(x)) this.listaEsport.push(x as Esports);`. No sé qué campos llevan tus objetos así que tal vez tengas que adaptar un poco el código, pero la idea es esa :)

Comment: Basicamente tengo el campo $key,name,type. No me funciona  lo que me has comentado me dice que la propiedad "contains" no existe en el tipo "Esport[]"

Comment: Prueba entonces `if(!this.listaEsport.some(es => es.name == x["name"])`o como sea que accedes a su nombre. El método [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/some) basicamente comprueba si algún elemento del array cumple el requisito especificado en la función que le pasas, ahí te dejo la documentación

Comment: ha funcionado, vaya locura, no sabia lo del some()

Comment: Bienvenido al fabuloso mundo de la programación, donde ***JAMÁS*** dejamos de aprender!. Te invito a que pongas la solución en una respuesta de manera elaborada para que sirva de ayuda a más gente :)